# meteor / react - What does the "readOnly" property do?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm very new to meteor / react programming and not very familiar with javascript so please excuse my ignorance.

I'm going through the meteor tutorial [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/temporary-ui-state) and am trying to understand the following line:

```
<input
    type='checkbox'
    readOnly={true}
    checked={this.state.hideCompleted}
    onClick={this.toggleHideCompleted} />
```

Specifically I'm trying to understand what the `readonly={true}` does and why this is needed.

Also, I tried googling and found this page which looks like the docs but it doesn't even mention this.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to have readOnly={true} because we want to disable the normal HTML behavior of what happens when you click it. Its state is already controlled by React with `checked={this.state.hideCompleted}`, and since there's no two-way binding in React, letting you just check or uncheck it as usual would mess with the application state. Instead, `this.state.hideCompleted` is changed in the `onClick` handler.

This way, when you click it, `this.toggleHideCompleted` is executed, probably doing `this.setState({hideCompleted : !this.state.hideCompleted})`, and the component is re-rendered with the new state.

Comment: so what is the expected behaviour if `readOnly={false}`. I tried it and nothing changed...

Comment: React actually saves you. It logs a warning to the console if you do that, and renders the checkbox as `readOnly={true}` anyway. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjolie/bqr6u6sL/ It's still good practice not to rely on some automatic fix functionality, and do it properly.